# after place order from redirect cart page magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9.1.1

I have an issue with the `Paypal express checkout payment method,`

I use Paypal express checkout payment method in Magento 1.9.1.1,

[image]when I place an order using Paypal,
but its redirects to the cart page.
please help me with this,

**System.log**

```
2021-10-20T09:44:56+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /home/test/public_html/test.com/app/design/frontend/default/framing/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml on line 118
```

thanks.

Comment: Does it show any error on the cart page?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya no, no any error shows on the cart page, when i click on place order button, it is automatically redirect on cart page from checkout page

Comment: have you check magento log files?

Comment: yes i edit my question with system.log error